# Google Cloud SQL: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm desperate since my Google Cloud SQL instance went down. I could connect to it yesterday without problem but since this morning i'm unable to connect to it in any way, it produces the following error: **The database server returned this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2013] Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0**

This is what I did to try to fix this:

- restart instance
- added authorized ip-addresses in CIDR notation
- reset root password
- restored backup
- pinged the ip-address and I get response

All these actions completed but i'm still unable to connect through:

- PHP
- MySQL workbench
- Ubuntu MySQL command line

All without luck. What could I do to repair my Cloud SQL instance. Is anyone else having this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. But no solution yet :(

Comment: I'm having the same issues atm. Problem seems to be with the Authorized networks. App engine instance seems to be connecting just fine.

Comment: You should ask this in an official Google support group.

Comment: They moved the group to StackOverflow. They monitor any post with the google-cloud-sql tag

Comment: Our Company is also facing the same problem. trying to resolve from morning. some time connection gets authorized and some time connection gets dropped.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm from the Cloud SQL team. We are looking into this issue, it should be resolved soon. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-sql-announce/SwomB2zuRDo. Updates will be posted on that thread (and if there's anything particularly important I'll edit this post).

The problem seems to only affect connections from outside Google Cloud. Clients connecting from App Engine and Compute Engine should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Our company has same problem.
We are unable to connect through both MySQL workbench and MySQL command line.
Our Google Appengine application has no problems to connect since its not using external IP.

Answer (score 0):

there.I encountered the same problem.You need to find out your public ip address,for that type "my public ip" in Google.Now click on your Cloud SQL instance that you created,under that click on ACCESS CONTROL tab and then click on Authorization tab under that.Under Authorized network,give any name you want to the network and copy your public ip address in the network.Now save changes and try to run the command from console.It should work fine.